# Get pixel color in canvas at position in console

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, canvas

I have want to debug my html5 canvas in Chrome console. I want to get the pixel color at position (445, 650).

I tried with this code:

```
var example = document.getElementById('glcanvas');
var context = example.getContext('2d');
var data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```

When I run those lines one by one, I get:

```
example
<canvas class="topleft" id="glcanvas" width="479" height="616" tabindex="1" contenteditable="true" style="cursor: default; width: 479px; height: 616px;"></canvas>

context
null
```

How can I get a **non-null** context?

Comment: Based on the id of gour element I'd guess it's an webgl context that has been initialised. Canvas elements can have only one context. So you'll need to ask for the same type as the one previously i itialised (canvas.getContext('webgl');) and then use the methods of this context. For webgl it would be readPixel.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks. I think this is the reason. Now context is not null anymore. I also tried readpixels but it says it requires 7 arguments. I don't know what to pass as parameters. Please, post an elaboration of your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Canvas elements can have **only one** Rendering Context attached to them. Every time you call `getContext(type)` after the first initialization, it will return either the same context object if you used the same `type` parameter, either `null` if you used an other context's `type`.

From your markup, it sounds that your canvas has an webgl context attached to it.
So when you call `getContext('2d')`, it will return `null`.

Here is an example showing you how to use it from an context you didn't directly initialized. 
The webgl's `getImageData` *equivalent method* is [`readPixels()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels).

```js
// we have access to the DOM element
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
// we need to get the correct context type, or it will return null
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('webgl2');
// where we'll store our pixels info
var pixels = new Uint8Array(4);

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  // we need to call it in the same execution flow as 'render' because webgl erase the drawing buffer by default
  // this can be done by stacking our code in the next frame.
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    console.log(pixels);
  });
});
```

```js
// we have access to the DOM element
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
// we need to get the correct context type, or it will return null
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('webgl2');
// where we'll store our pixels info
var pixels = new Uint8Array(4);

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  // we need to call it in the same execution flow as 'render' because webgl erase the drawing buffer by default
  // this can be done by stacking our code in the next frame.
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    console.log(pixels);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- 
Example of external code, on which we don't have direct access.
Taken from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html
-->

<base href="https://threejs.org/examples/">
<script src="../build/three.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var mesh;
  init();
  animate();
  console.clear();

  function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    //
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
  }

  function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
</script>
```

Note that the pixel reading operation becomes async, and will always be one frame late in this implementation, because the webgl context was not initialized with the `preserveDrawingBuffer` option. If it were, you could make an synchronous method.

There is also one type agnostic way to do it : use an offscreen 2d context and draw the canvas directly on this 2d context.

```js
// the canvas we want to read
var target = document.querySelector('canvas');
// the canvas we'll use to read the target on
var reader = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = reader.getContext('2d');

target.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - target.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.clientY - target.offsetTop;
  // same preserveDrawingBuffer workaround
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    // move the target image in the top left corner of our reader,
    //  because we want only a single pixel
    ctx.drawImage(target, -x, -y); 
    var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
    console.log(pixels);
  });
});
```

```js
// the canvas we want to read
var target = document.querySelector('canvas');
// the canvas we'll use to read the target on
var reader = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = reader.getContext('2d');

target.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - target.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.clientY - target.offsetTop;
  // same preserveDrawingBuffer workaround
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    // move the target image in the top left corner of our reader,
    //  because we want only a single pixel
    ctx.drawImage(target, -x, -y); 
    var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
    console.log(pixels);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- 
Example of external code, on which we don't have direct access.
Taken from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html
-->

<base href="https://threejs.org/examples/">
<script src="../build/three.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var mesh;
    init();
    animate();
    console.clear();

    function init() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 400;
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(200, 200, 200);
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(mesh);
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      //
      window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
      mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually your Code works fine.

Here is a HTML/Script-Code which contains the given Information of your question.

```
<html>
<canvas class="topleft" id="glcanvas" width="479" height="616" tabindex="1" contenteditable="true" style="cursor: default; width: 479px; height: 616px;"></canvas>
<script>
var example = document.getElementById('glcanvas');
var context = example.getContext('2d');
var x=445;
var y=650;
var data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
alert('R:' + data[0] + ' G:' + data[1] + ' B:' + data[2]);
</script>
</html>
```

Probably you are running your Script before the initialization of the glcanvas-Object.